# Querying an array to populate a table view in Swift using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm querying a Parse class for the current user's username. The class column is named **Attendants** and the array definitely contains the username. When the code is ran, the table isn't populated and no errors are thrown. 
Would anybody be able to point out what I'm doing wrong?
Necessary code is shown below:

```
class EventsViewController: PFQueryTableViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Event"
        self.textKey = "username"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = false
    }

    // Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Event")
        var tempname = PFUser.currentUser().username
        NSLog(tempname)

        query.whereKey("Attendants", equalTo: tempname)
        return query
    }

    //override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! PFTableViewCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        cell?.textLabel?.text = object["EventName"] as! String!
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = object["EventName"] as! String!
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell
    }

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! EventDetailViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            detailScene.currentObject = objects[row] as? PFObject
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

Comment: i don't see where you call the query function...

Comment: I don't see `numberOfRowsInSection`, is it returning the right number of cells?

Comment: Which of your methods are called? Have you implemented the objects loaded method to see what results the query returns?

Comment: The query does return the correct rows when another column which isn't an array is queried.

Comment: @Volker the query function is called by the tableviewcontroller itself

Comment: @PortlandRunner This function is not used in this case, the tableview controller itself will call all these functions, you just need to make sure the query function is written and the tvc is initialized

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is write the `queryForTable()` function.
All your tableView functions are never called.
So something about this would be solution:

```
class EventsViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
    self.textKey = "YOUR_PARSE_COLOMN_YOU_WANT_TO_SHOW"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Event")
    var tempname = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
    NSLog(tempname!)
    // This is really ugly.. Please do this via Pointer and not via String.
    query.whereKey("Attendants", equalTo: tempname!)
    return query
}
}
```

If you want to use custom cells, you need to create your own TableViewController and implement the logic on the TableViewController itself.

> This code is tested in Xcode 6.3 (swift 1.2)

Please keep in mind that you need to init the tableViewController out of the code, like:

```
var eventsvc = EventsViewController(style: .Plain, className: "Event")
```

to present it out of a viewcontroller:

```
self.presentViewController(eventsvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you want to use is it in a storyboard [see this](https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-use-storyboards-with-pfquerytableviewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks for that, worked perfectly. However I've decided not to use the PFTable, instead I'll use a normal UITableViewController.
Having another issue but thanks for the help!